# Is it possible to send a raw, signed transaction from an ethereum contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, evm

Does the EVM support this? Does solidity allow this? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

In theory it is possible for a transaction to an Ethereum contract to calculate a signature and create a signed transaction. However, this is hardly ever useful, as signing a transaction requires a private key, and private keys are not usually useful unless they are private.

If the goal is to trigger some action to another contract, your code can simply call that contract. There is no need to sign a transaction.

If the goal is to have a transaction sent to the blockchain at a later date, this can be accomplished by incentivizing someone else to send the transaction. See the [Ethereum Alarm Clock](http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/) for an example.

Comment: I want one contract to send a transaction signed by a wallet to another contract. The transaction will be signed before being put on the blockchain, keeping the private key safe.

Comment: In that case the answer is no, a contract can't do networking, so it can't send stuff to the network. However, if you can explain what problem you're trying to solve there's probably a solution that doesn't require you to do this.

Comment: How about we send the approval a a signed transaction within the call we make. Execute the sign approval and then execute the call made?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what you want to do but [Multisig wallets](https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/solidity/MultiSigWallet.sol) allow arbitrary transactions to be sent from them. You create a raw transaction without signing and sent it to the multisig wallet with `submitTransaction(destination, txValue, txData)`.

When the required amount of confirmations is achieved through `confirmTransaction` the raw transaction is executed with something like this

```
destination.call.value(txValue)(txData);
```

txData can be anything. For example if destination is a token contract, then txData can be a token transfer "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000012345678901234567890123456789012345678900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000".

- 0xa9059cbb transfer(destination,amount)
- 0000000000000000000000001234567890123456789012345678901234567890 destination address
- 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000 amount to transfer